# Linking Firebase to BigQuery results in an error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to link Firebase project to GCP using the FIrebase console and I keep getting an error.

The Firebase UI is showing an error:
"An error occurred while trying to link. Please try again."

And checking the actual response that the Firebase console receives shows this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The requst as seen in the Network tab on Google chrome:

```
advertisingIdsState: "EXPORTED"
analyticsSourceOfTruth: "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS"
crashlyticsBigqueryStreamExportState: "STREAM_EXPORT_ENABLED"
enabledProducts: ["ANALYTICS", "CRASHLYTICS", "FCM"]
0: "ANALYTICS"
1: "CRASHLYTICS"
2: "FCM"
```

1. I have done this many times and never received an error like this.
2. I do have the permissions to do this (I am an admin + I gave myself the permission of Editor )
3. Double checked and BigQuery is enabled for my project
4. There are other logs which show up on my BigQuery so its working properly
5. Google support is refusing to look into this from some reason

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages), this error returns when there is any kind of invalid input other than an invalid query, such as missing required fields or an invalid table schema. Invalid queries return an invalidQuery error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted Firebase support and they acknowledged this issue. They supplied the following workaround which actually works:

> As a workaround you could try these steps for now to link your project
> to BigQuery:
>
> - Go to Project settings > Integrations
> - BigQuery card, click link
> - About linking Firebase to BigQuery, click next
> - Select the products you want to configure **except** for Google Analytics
> - Click link to BigQuery
>
> After that, you have now successfully linked your Firebase project to
> BigQuery. And if you want to enable Google Analytics for your project
> just toggle the button and you’re all set.