# Not able to link Firebase project to BigQuery

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery

I am trying to link my Firebase project to BigQuery. It seems to not work and every time clicking the "Link to BigQuery" fails with this error (screenshot attached) even though I am the owner of the project. I could not find any more details about what is the issue. The same project successfully links to Google Analytics. Would be great to get any inputs on fixing this issue. [image]

Comment: There's a guide that you can follow on [linking your Firebase project to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

Comment: Manage to resolve this by enabling Firebase Management API. It showed up on the network error.

Comment: Please post your solution here as an answer so that anyone who experience this issue will help them. Also check this [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Answered on this thread with an official response from Firebase support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71149521/1544519

Answer (score 0):

Based on inputs from firebase support team I was able to resolve this issue. We need to enable `Firebase Management API` in https://console.cloud.google.com/. I have put down the error response which you can lookout if the error occurs.

[image]